# python: AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'count'

Tags: python

Tenho um código que está me retornando o seguinte erro

```
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'count'...
```

Tenho uma lista com vários números e preciso saber quantas vezes se repete números de 1 a 13. O código abaixo é apenas um exemplo pequeno para depois transpor isso tudo para algo maior.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

number_sequence = [
    16, 19, 1, 3, 8, 11, 18, 21, 13, 9, 24, 5, 23, 10, 6, 22, 19, 25, 3,
    2, 21, 20, 23, 24, 18, 9, 4, 6, 8, 15, 16, 22, 5, 25, 11, 14, 9, 4,
    13, 17, 15, 3, 10, 8, 6, 10, 15, 19, 7, 9, 8, 20, 22, 16, 4, 18, 1,
    11, 5, 21, 19, 1, 25, 7, 20, 22, 13, 8, 3, 17, 2, 15, 14, 12, 18, 18,
    25, 12, 8, 20, 24, 22, 4, 11, 14, 3, 23, 15, 10, 21, 10, 1, 4, 25,
    19, 7, 22, 11, 9, 23, 17, 14, 13, 18, 3, 7, 6, 23, 14, 1, 19, 8, 5,
    11, 25, 9, 16, 4, 17, 21, 7, 20, 6, 5, 21, 1, 17, 12, 16, 24, 3,
    23, 22, 4, 18, 1, 12, 4, 18, 7, 20, 11, 10, 2, 25, 14, 21, 6, 19, 23
]

for n in range(1, 14):
    print(n.count(number_sequence))
```

Não entendo o porque deste erro visto que se eu rodar apenas uma ocorrência por vez ele funciona certinho sem nenhum erro.

Por exemplo: `print(sequence_numbers.count(5))`

Comment: `n.count(number_sequence)`, você inverteu. O correto é: `number_sequence.count(n)`

Comment: Problema resolvido, muito obrigado Anderson Carlos Woss... Vou ficar bom nisso ainda, rsrsr. O erro foi tão bobo que nem to acreditando...

Answer (score 2):

Você inverteu o a chamada do método count.

Você está chamando o método count a partir do inteiro:

```
n.count(number_sequence)
```

Porém o método `count` é pertencente a [lista](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/list_count.htm) e conta quantas vezes um determinado valor aparece em uma lista.

```
number_sequence.count(n)
```

O código ficaria assim:

```
number_sequence = [
    16, 19, 1, 3, 8, 11, 18, 21, 13, 9, 24, 5, 23, 10, 6, 22, 19, 25, 3,
    2, 21, 20, 23, 24, 18, 9, 4, 6, 8, 15, 16, 22, 5, 25, 11, 14, 9, 4,
    13, 17, 15, 3, 10, 8, 6, 10, 15, 19, 7, 9, 8, 20, 22, 16, 4, 18, 1,
    11, 5, 21, 19, 1, 25, 7, 20, 22, 13, 8, 3, 17, 2, 15, 14, 12, 18, 18,
    25, 12, 8, 20, 24, 22, 4, 11, 14, 3, 23, 15, 10, 21, 10, 1, 4, 25,
    19, 7, 22, 11, 9, 23, 17, 14, 13, 18, 3, 7, 6, 23, 14, 1, 19, 8, 5,
    11, 25, 9, 16, 4, 17, 21, 7, 20, 6, 5, 21, 1, 17, 12, 16, 24, 3,
    23, 22, 4, 18, 1, 12, 4, 18, 7, 20, 11, 10, 2, 25, 14, 21, 6, 19, 23
]


for n in range(1, 14):
    print 'O numéro %s se repete %s vezes.' % (n, number_sequence.count(n))
```

Answer (score 1):

Dá para resolver criando um variavel que armazene a quantia de vezes que os números de 1 a 13 aparecem.

```
number_sequence = [
    16, 19, 1, 3, 8, 11, 18, 21, 13, 9, 24, 5, 23, 10, 6, 22, 19, 25, 3,
    2, 21, 20, 23, 24, 18, 9, 4, 6, 8, 15, 16, 22, 5, 25, 11, 14, 9, 4,
    13, 17, 15, 3, 10, 8, 6, 10, 15, 19, 7, 9, 8, 20, 22, 16, 4, 18, 1,
    11, 5, 21, 19, 1, 25, 7, 20, 22, 13, 8, 3, 17, 2, 15, 14, 12, 18, 18,
    25, 12, 8, 20, 24, 22, 4, 11, 14, 3, 23, 15, 10, 21, 10, 1, 4, 25,
    19, 7, 22, 11, 9, 23, 17, 14, 13, 18, 3, 7, 6, 23, 14, 1, 19, 8, 5,
    11, 25, 9, 16, 4, 17, 21, 7, 20, 6, 5, 21, 1, 17, 12, 16, 24, 3,
    23, 22, 4, 18, 1, 12, 4, 18, 7, 20, 11, 10, 2, 25, 14, 21, 6, 19, 23
]
# Variavel contadora
count = 0
for n in number_sequence:
    #Ela é incrementada toda vez que que o numero dentro do laço for de 1 a 13
    if(n >= 1 and n <= 13): count += 1

print ("Os Números de 1 a 13 se apareceram", count , "vezes")
```

Comment: `n >= 1 and n <= 13` poderia ser reescrito como `1 <= n <= 13` para simplificar

Comment: Obrigado, estou conhecendo agora a linguagem então não sei muito sobre a mesma.

Comment: Lucas Emanuel seu código tbm é interessante, porém a solução anterior do Anderson Carlos Woss foi a que melhor me atendeu (na realidade foi apenas uma inversão que eu fiz em meu código), pois oque eu precisava fazer era saber a quantidade de vezes em cada número se repetia dentro da lista, ex: nº 8 se repete 7x, o nº 9 6x e daí por diante. No caso para a saída seria print('[{:0>2}] repete: {} vezes' .format(n, number_sequence.count(n)))... Narealidade nem vou printar essa saída, vou usa-la em uma lista secundária para plotar em um gráfico matplotlib